Show about an alien planet with repetitive color sequence movies
I'm trying to remember a movie/show where the main character is taken to an alien planet as an ambassador for Earth. While there he is getting to know the culture and in the process is shown one of their best films. To him it is just a sequence of colors, something like green, blue, red, orange, yellow, and that's all. He sees other movies and notices that all the successful movies are the same sequence, and uses that knowledge to become a movie director.
He becomes wildly successful, creating many best selling films, but eventually becomes hooked to one of their drugs and his life starts to fall apart.
I believe that this was an animated piece, and I saw it within the last 5 years, but I don't know when it was created. I watched in on a streaming service (I don't remember which one unfortunately), and it was contained with one episode, though I don't remember if that was one movie, or one episode of a show.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you see this?  How long was it?

Edited to answer!

If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. Incorrect answers are an excellent chance to [edit] in newly remembered details, e.g. "I know it wasn't Betelgeuse Bollywood because all of the aliens had three big horns and a wooly jaw, and the film was in Esperanto, and didn't look dubbed."

Might it be the 2015 short Movies in Space?

MOVIES IN SPACE is a comedy sci-fi following the rise and fall of Travis Shepard, a future-earth-ambassador, who unwittingly gets caught up in an alien Hollywood-like system.

The review in this article mentions the drug problems.


This was an unexpected delight. Chris Smith’s sci-fi/comedy genre-bender “Movies in Space” was a standout of the shorts program. An astronaut, Travis Shepherd, in the not-too-distant future becomes Earth’s ambassador to an alien race. Along the way, he moves in with an aspiring filmmaker and inadvertently becomes the most famous production mogul in history. But, as with any rise, there is a fall and Travis struggles with space drugs, space sex and space fame. The jokes are densely packed, the comedy both broad and ironic, the effects outstanding and the story compelling both comedically and emotionally.

A quick watch of the short reveals that, indeed, all of the films are a series color changes allowing with some beeps and buzzes. The "alien" is basically a regular human except that they talk in a very high-pitched voice.
Complete short - official release by the creators



Found with a search for site:imdb.com alien ambassador becomes film director

This is it! I guess I misremembered the animated part of it. Thanks so much!

That was awesome. I loved the ending. Green, man. I didn't see that coming.

I recently saw another SF comedy short of theirs, I Need It Yesterday, which i thought was wonderful.

These guys are really good fun. Big fan.
